# Accessing array of objects from another class

Tags: java

i'm stuck on this code. I'm trying to access an array of objects from another class and compare it in my method.

```
public static double averageUserscore(GameScore[] scores, int numScores, String name) {

        double sum;
        int playerScores = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numScores;) {
            if(???? == name) {
                sum = sum + scores[i];
                playerScores++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to compare [i]th GameScore userName which is in another class to name.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information as to what you want to do? You're looking to compare the String `name` to an array of names? Where is that array?

Comment: is it on the other class of GameScore, basically what im trying to do is to compare the objects in that array of GameScore is same with the name

Comment: What does the `GameScore` class look like?

Comment: //method for storing all users input in parameters
    public GameScore(String newUserName, int newUserScore) {
        userName = newUserName;
        userScore = newUserScore;
    }

Comment: it also includes all the getters and setters for every parameters

Comment: I don't see the array in the `GameScore` class, but if you have one, you should be able to pass it to your `averageUserScore` method and iterate through it comparing each name to the given name

Comment: make the string Public static then you can call it anywhere via imports

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.  To compare Strings in java do not use `==`

```
for(int i = 0; i < numScores;) {
    if(scoares[i].getUserName().equals(name)) {
        sum = sum + scores[i].getUserScore();
        playerScores++;
        // maybe break; if only one that should match
    }
}
```

Comment: it compiles now thanks, but i can't run it yet. There is an error with sum + scores[i] since i cant add class object to double. Do you think i can do the same with this one? like scores[i].getUserScore?

Comment: @JyleVillagracia Yes, you are right, I have edited my answer